# Как вывести среднее запросом

Tags: sql, postgresql

Вот идея такая - есть 2 датчика для отгрузки и датчик расхода воды.

Нужно просуммировать данные по отгрузке и поделить на расход воды и вывести графиком

получается нужно брать интервалы времени(данные идут раз в 30 секунд), например 2 минуты, затем находить среднее по каждому датчику, и уже со средними оперировать.

таким образом могу выдернуть за час

```
SELECT avg(CASE WHEN id = 28 THEN value::REAL ELSE 0 END) 
/ (avg(CASE WHEN id = 37 THEN value::REAL ELSE 0 END) + 
avg(CASE WHEN id = 38 THEN value::REAL ELSE 0 END))
FROM data_ins
WHERE id IN (28,
             37,
             38)
  AND f_time > now() - interval '1 hour'
```

но мне то нужен ответ вида

```
 value   time
 100     2015-10-10 10:00:00
 111     2015-10-10 10:02:00  
 101     2015-10-10 10:04:00
```

таблица

```
 id   value   timestamp
```

пока дошел до такого

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(f_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'),
   avg (VALUE::numeric), ID
  FROM "SC_Tag".data_ins
  WHERE id IN (28,
               37,
               38)
    AND f_time > now() - interval '1 hour' 
    GROUP BY TO_CHAR(f_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'), id
    order by TO_CHAR(f_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') desc
```

по логике если сделать проверку на наличие значения должно сработать

```
SELECT avg(CASE WHEN t_.id = 28 THEN t_.value::REAL ELSE 0 END) 
/ (avg(CASE WHEN t_.id = 37 THEN t_.value::REAL ELSE 0 END) 
+ avg(CASE WHEN t_.id = 38 THEN t_.value::REAL ELSE 0 END)),
       f_time
FROM
  ( SELECT TO_CHAR(f_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')||':00' AS f_time,
                                                           AVG (VALUE::numeric) AS value,
                                                                                   ID
   FROM "SC_Tag".data_ins
   WHERE id IN (28,
                37,
                38)
     AND f_time > now() - interval '1 hour'
   GROUP BY TO_CHAR(f_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'),
            id
   ORDER BY TO_CHAR(f_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') DESC ) t_
GROUP BY f_time
```

Comment: Из примера не ясна структура таблицы, в частности, как определяется источник (датчик) текущего значения. Посему, рабочий пример привести не могу. В общем случае, нужно получить интересующие значения времени с нужным интервалом и в зависимоти от них использовать соответсвующие значение соответсвующих датчиков. Интересующие значения времени можно сгенерировать при помощи generate_series. А можно расчитать из значений в самой таблице. Второй способ будет сложнее в реализации, но эффективнее в работе. PS: что-то мне подсказывает, что брать таки нужно не среднее, а разницу max()-min()

Comment: может тут оконную функцию нужно использовать? http://www.depesz.com/2010/09/12/how-to-group-messages-into-chats/

Comment: Все еще не ясно, как же понять, где в таблице данные отгрузки, а где расхода.

Comment: по ид. 28 - расход. 37 и 38 - отгрузка

Comment: @des1roer У вас вопрос сформулирован так, что из него вытекает только проблема с группировкой. А математику поправить не имея вашей базы не реально. С виду тот вариант который вы последним указали в вопросе должен все посчитать правильно. Хотя в вопросе "и поделить на расход воды", а вы делите наоборот расход на отгрузку

Comment: не суть. последний запрос валится, так как деление на ноль. можно как то через case это отловить? то есть нет гарантии что есть все 3 числа

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для реализации интрервала в 2 минуты приведем значения времени к минуте и в случае нечетной минуты, отнимем единицу.

Далее соберем среднии значения в эти интервалы времени и по этим данным уже можно делать окончательные расчеты.

Для исключения из выборки интервалов с отсутствием данных на одном из типов датчиков, можно воспользоваться фильтрацией having (если нужно вывести все данные с использованием дефолтных значений в case, то соответсвенно убрать **having count(*) = 2**).

```
with data as (
  select date_trunc('minutes', f_time) - (extract('minutes' from f_time)::integer % 2) * '1 minute'::interval as tstamp,
  case
    when id = 28 then 'отгруз'
    else 'расход'
  end as sensor,
  avg(value) as value
  from data_ins
  where id in (28, 37, 38)
  and f_time >= now() - '1 hour'::interval
  group by 1,2
)

select tstamp,
sum(case when sensor='отгруз' then value else 0 end)/ sum(case when sensor='расход' then value else 99999999.99 end)
from data
group by 1
having count(*) = 2
order by 1
```

PS: Приведенные варианты

> avg(CASE WHEN id = 38 THEN value::REAL ELSE 0 END))

не годятся, ибо нулевое значение будет учитываться в рассчетах и влиять на результат.

Ну и само собой, не стоит в знаменатели нули пихать, посему в качестве отсутвия данных мною использовалось большое значение, результат вычесления при котором не уронит запрос но будет заметен в результатах.

Пару слов о использовании sum() во втором запросе. Вместо avg() используется sum() поскольку в data на конретный интервал мы уже имеем единственное среднее значение для каждого типа датчиков и рассчитывать его не нужно. При использовании avg() на результат повлияет else значение, на sum() же ноль никак не повлияет, а для большого значения результат большим и останется, то что нужно. Своего рода маленький хак использования агрегирующих функций с учетом специфики набора данных. Вместо sum() с таким же успехом можно было взять и max(), оно даже несколько и логичнее будет.

Comment: при отсутствии данных вообще ничего писать не надо. думается проще сделать функцию, возвращающую значение либо null

Comment: Если никаких данных не будет то и значений выведено не будет, ибо взять не где. Другое дело, что может получится ситуация, когда с одного типа датчиков данные есть, а с другого нет. Неуж-то и такие данные дужно скипать? Если так, то это также исправимо, к примеру, добавлением having count(*) = 2 к результирующей выборке

Comment: единственно что и значение нужно в таком случае делить на 2. так а раз в минуту это как сделать? думаю мало точек будет

Comment: Не понял, зачем делить на 2? Если это о `having count(*) = 2`, то неверно поняли суть этой фильтрации, советую почитать о [having](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-HAVING). В data на каждое значение интервала имеется от одной до 2-х записей. having count(*) = 2 выбрасывает значения с одной записью и выдает только с 2-мя, т.е. с данными по датчикам обоих типов (отгруз и расход). Для получения данных на каждую минуту просто уберите вычитаение единицы для нечетных, т.е. `- (extract('minutes' from f_time)::integer % 2) * '1 minute'::interval as tstamp `

Comment: делить на 2 - потому что ответ за 2 минуты, и почему sum а не avg

Comment: @des1roer, так среднее что за 2 минуты, что за 1 минуту, это же среднее. Объяснение использования sum() вместо avg() добавлено к ответу.